# Telerik RadGrid not displaying records

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am having an issue displaying data in a RadGrid.  There is data in the datasource, but the RadGrid does not display it.

**aspx code:**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Width="980px" 
EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"
AllowAutomaticDeletes="false" 
AllowAutomaticInserts="false"
AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" 
AllowPaging="true" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False"              
AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="false" 
AutoGenerateEditColumn="false" 
ItemStyle-Height="20px" 
ClientSettings-ActiveRowIndex="true"
EnableViewState = "false" 
OnNeedDataSource = "RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
<MasterTableView AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10" Width="980px" EnableViewState="true"
    RetrieveAllDataFields="false">
    <NoRecordsTemplate>There is no data available.</NoRecordsTemplate>

    <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column"></ExpandCollapseColumn>
    <Columns>                    
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TripId" HeaderText="Trip ID" SortExpression="TripID" UniqueName="TripId"  
            SortAscImageUrl="SortAsc.gif" SortDescImageUrl="SortDesc.gif">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TripLegId" HeaderText="TripLegId" SortExpression="TripLegId" UniqueName="TripLegId" 
            SortAscImageUrl="SortAsc.gif" SortDescImageUrl="SortDesc.gif">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MemberFirstName" HeaderText="Member First Name" SortExpression="MemberFirstName"
            UniqueName="MemberFirstName" 
            SortAscImageUrl="SortAsc.gif" SortDescImageUrl="SortDesc.gif">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>

    <PagerStyle FirstPageImageUrl="PagingFirst.gif" 
        LastPageImageUrl="PagingLast.gif" NextPageImageUrl="PagingNext.gif" 
        PrevPageImageUrl="PagingPrev.gif" />
    <CommandItemStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0066CC" />
</MasterTableView>
<ClientSettings>
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
</ClientSettings>
<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>            
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**.cs code**

```
public void btnSearch_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = GetTripsDataSet();
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
        this.RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        ViewState["newset"] = "new";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errMessage = ex.Source.ToString();
    }
}  

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["newset"] == null) return;

    if (Session["gridTrips"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["griTrips"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to set Session["gridTrips"] ? Try calling RadGrid1.Rebind()

Comment: Also remove RadGrid1.DataSource = GetTripsDataSet();
        RadGrid1.DataBind();

Answer (score 1):

You just need to rebind the grid, which will automatically call the grid's NeedDataSource event.

```
public void btnSearch_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.RadGrid1.Rebind();
        this.RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        ViewState["newset"] = "new";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errMessage = ex.Source.ToString();
    }
}  

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["newset"] == null) return;

    if (Session["gridTrips"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["griTrips"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
            this.RadGrid1.VirtualItemCount = dt.Rows.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

It's also good to set the grid's `VirtualItemCount` property, especially if you're using custom paging.  From the Telerik RadGrid metadata on this property:

> Summary:
>       Gets or sets a value, indicating the total number of items in the data source
>       when custom paging is used. Thus the grid "understands" that the data source
>       contains the specified number of records and it should fetch merely part
>       of them at a time to execute requested operation.
>
> Remarks:
>       If you set a value that is greater than the actual number of items, RadGrid
>       will show all available items plus empty pages (or whatever other content
>       you set) for the items that exceed the actual number.
>       For example you have a data source with 9'000 items and you set VirtualItemCount
>       to 10'000. If your page size is 1000, the grid will render 10 pages and the
>       last page will be empty (or with NoRecordsTemplate if you're using such).